# Masses timetable

Tags: church-local, timetable

I'm sorry if this is not the right place where asking this question.

I'm trying to set up a database of cult (or masses) timetables all over the world, starting from Italy, and I would need some source where asking for timetables or grab the data about timetables.

I want to start from Italy, where I found the [site](http://www.vicariatusurbis.org/?page_id=190&TipoEnte=1) of Rome diocese with all the curches infos, including masses timetables .

What I need is some site where I can find the name of the church and the schedule of the cults (or masses).

Does anybody know where to find any site (i.e. data-source) like the one I cited where I can grab data?

Comment: I'm sorry, but can you expand on your questions a little more? What exactly are you looking for?

Comment: I edited the quesiton. Is it more understandable now?

Comment: So, you're basically asking for a list of churches and when they hold their services?  Ultimately, I think that is too localized.

Comment: masstimes.org is pretty good, they must maintain a database with no API that you could use and I think it'd be pretty hard to screen scrape them (plus they did all the work so it wouldn't be nice either).  But what is the info in that link?  What's the deal with the suppressed cults? Do they never just rename the churches?

Comment: I don't want to steal their information. I want to do it in Italy and Europe. Masstimes.org is wonderful!

Comment: How many parishes have websites in Italy? If you could get them to put a file on their sites to aggregate their mass times, that would be pretty awesome.

Comment: Whato do you mean exactly with "put a file on their sites to aggregate their mass times"?

Comment: @DanieleB sorry I missed that comment. I mean, something like [microformats](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Microformat) but for Mass times.   If I went to www.staugustinefootville.org/masstimes.xml (my home parish's website)  and got some list of mass times, you could make a web page that would collect all that info into one giant store of mass times.

Comment: [WikkiMissa](http://wikkimissa.org/) is a good one. Its admin pulls his data from a handful of sources.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It would be awesome, but there is no global Catholic Mass timetable. 
for the united states, [MassTimes.org](http://www.masstimes.org/) is the usual best bet, with going to a particular diocese' website and hoping that they have links parishes you want.

Lots of parishes post their bulletins to [SeekAndFind.com](http://seekandfind.com/) so you can build a list of mass times from that.  But that's way, way, way to cumbersome.

Personally, I'd be very interested in making a parish-life aggregator as an open source application because I don't think one exists.

Comment: I would kindof like a schedule of the annual carnivals for Catholic Parishes. :)

Comment: yeah, especially considering the Bishop's want us to abstain from meat on Fridays this year. Would be nice to have a Fish Fry Finder.